urdf_tutorial error
im trying to use urdf tutorial to visualize the model with rviz :
ros2 launch urdf_tutorial display.launch.py model:=my_robot.urdf
and i got this error :
INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ken2/.ros/log/2024-06-27-23-20-31-042085-ken2PC-74760
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): executed command failed. Command: xacro /opt/ros/humble/share/urdf_tutorial/my_robot.urdf
Captured stderr output: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 1012, in parse
    inp = f = open(filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/ros/humble/share/urdf_tutorial/my_robot.urdf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 1119, in _process
    doc = process_file(input_file_name, **opts)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 1096, in process_file
    doc = parse(None, input_file_name)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 1016, in parse
    raise XacroException(e.strerror + ": " + e.filename, exc=e)
xacro.XacroException: No such file or directory: /opt/ros/humble/share/urdf_tutorial/my_robot.urdf [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/ros/humble/share/urdf_tutorial/my_robot.urdf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/bin/xacro", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('xacro==2.0.8', 'console_scripts', 'xacro')())
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 1171, in main
    _process(input_file_name, vars(opts))
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 1124, in _process
    except xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError as e:
AttributeError: module 'xml' has no attribute 'parsers'

also when i try to build my workspace this happens :
[0.822s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_core.prefix_path.colcon:The path '/home/ken2/ros2_ws/install' in the environment variable COLCON_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist
[0.822s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.ament:The path '/home/ken2/ros2_ws/install/urdf_tutorial' in the environment variable AMENT_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist


If you look at this particular section of the trace:
xacro.XacroException: No such file or directory: /opt/ros/humble/share/urdf_tutorial/my_robot.urdf [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/ros/humble/share/urdf_tutorial/my_robot.urdf'

You will see that the file that xacro is trying to access is located at /opt/ros/humble. I do not think your URDF file is located there.
Also, if you look at the display.launch.py file present in the urdf_tutorial package, you see that the default path is always searching for the urdf_tutorial package, which is located in /opt/ros/humble.
You should create your own description package which contains the urdf, the xacro, and the launch file. You can also simply clone the urdf_tutorials package into your workspace, change the package name and put your URDF file inside this new package. If all goes well, you should be able to visualise your URDF now.
